# Create Note from iCloud.com

Tags: icloud, notes.app

Is it possible to create a new note soley by logging into iCloud.com? Also, though I can see my existing notes synced up there, I cannot edit them. Is this the default behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[icloud.com](http://icloud.com) does not have a notes feature at this time. It is rumored that around the time that iOS 6 is released, icloud.com will be updated to include notes and reminders. Previews of these features might be available to you already, if you are an Apple registered developer and have updated your iOS device to an iOS 6 beta, by visiting [beta.icloud.com](http://beta.icloud.com)

Comment: Hi, you might want to amend your answer as iCloud.com has added support.

Answer (score 1):

As [of September 13, 2012](http://www.theverge.com/2012/9/13/3329310/icloud-com-update-reminders-notes-find-my-iphone-lost-mode), [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com) has Notes and Reminders apps added, so you can directly access the iCloud-synced notes and reminders data on the web.

It's worth noting that you're required to have an iCloud email address for the notes syncing. If your notes are set to sync with another address (such as Gmail), the web app can't access them. I believe this is because the Notes syncing still uses IMAP behind the scenes (each note is just a mail message in an IMAP folder).